# onclick second click

Tags: c#, asp.net

New to asp.net, I am having a problem on a website I am creating, I am using a master page to build my pages.  I am trying to change the css class of a li tag using the onclick event in linkbuttons:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="AboutButton" OnClick="about_click" PostBackUrl="about.aspx"><span>About</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

This linkbutton calls a function in the master page's code behind:

```
protected void about_click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    if(Page.IsPostBack)  
    {       
        about.Attributes.Add`enter code here`("class", "current");  
    }  
}
```

This only works when the page is loaded and the button is clicked again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any constraints on what you can use for this? I wouldn't recommend to do this on the onclick server event, I recommend you to use javascript or jquery and do the change on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

By adding: `if(Page.IsPostBack)` you're specifically telling it not to execute that code the first time the page is loaded, but you want it to happen when the page is first loaded, by the sounds of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add `if(Page.IsPostBack)`. Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)  
    {       
        about.Attributes.Add("class", "current"); //initial setting here 
    }  
}

protected void about_click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    about.Attributes.Add("class", "current");  
}
```